# Sequelize mysql adding pagination makes model not recognize associated models

Tags: pagination, sequelize.js, limit

I have 2 tables: InvoiceItems and Products and my api has an endpoint to retrieve the most popular products (by most sales) so I join Invoice to products, add a new column which is the sum of quantities per product and group by InvoiceItems.product_id. My code is

```js
const x = await Product.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'name', 
                [Sequelize.fn("SUM", Sequelize.col("InvoiceItems.quantity")), "totalQuantity"] // aggregates all products and quantities into 1 row
            ], 
            include: {
                model: InvoiceItem,
                attributes: []
            },
            group: ['product_id'], // Groups  aggregates into n products
            order: [ ['totalQuantity', 'DESC'] ],
        })
```

This works fine and logs

```sql
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name`, SUM(`InvoiceItems`.`quantity`) AS `totalQuantity` FROM `products` AS `Product` LEFT OUTER JOIN `invoice_items` AS `InvoiceItems` ON `Product`.`id` = `InvoiceItems`.`product_id` GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY `totalQuantity` DESC
```

But when I add limit or offset in my findAll I get an sqlerror

```
 name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
 parent: Error: Unknown column 'InvoiceItems.quantity' in 'field list'
```

and logs

```
 {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'InvoiceItems.quantity' in 'field list'",
    sql: 'SELECT `Product`.* FROM (SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name`, SUM(`InvoiceItems`.`quantity`) AS `totalQuantity` FROM `products` AS `Product` GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY `Product`.`totalQuantity` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `Product` LEFT OUTER JOIN `invoice_items` AS `InvoiceItems` ON `Product`.`id` = `InvoiceItems`.`product_id` ORDER BY `totalQuantity` DESC;',
    parameters: undefined
  }
```